# How to remove first X lines from file up to the first occurrence of particular string?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, postgresql

I have many PostgreSQL dump files such this and because I import these files automatically into another database server (H2) and `SET` command is not compatible with this database, I need to remove all lines up to the very first `INSERT` command.

How can I do it in shell script?

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.8
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.8

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- Data for Name: workgroups; Type: TABLE DATA; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

INSERT INTO public.workgroups.....
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^INSERT/,$p' file.sql
```

- It says print the data from the line which begins with `INSERT ...` to the end.

  - From desired pattern: `/^INSERT/`
  - To the `,`
  - End `$`
  - Print `p`

To modify the file instead of viewing it:

```
sed -n -i.bk '/^INSERT/,$p' file.sql
```

- It would keep the original files with `.bk` suffix.

To run it on all files:

```
sed -n -i.bk '/^INSERT/,$p' ~/path/to/sql_dir/*.sql
```

For example:

```
Foo
Bar
FooBar
INSERT Foo
Fantastic
```

Would become:

```
INSERT Foo
Fantastic
```

Comment: Perfect! And I'm wondering how not to store backup file and instead replace the original file?

Comment: That would be `sed -n -i` without `.bk` like: `sed -n -i '/^INSERT/,$p' file.sql`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `awk`:

```bsh
awk '/^INSERT/{x=1}x==1' <in >out        # including the INSERT line
awk 'x==1{print}/^INSERT/{x=1}' <in >out # including the INSERT line
```

This reads the file `in` line by line and sets `x=1` if a line beginning with “INSERT” is found. If `x` is 1, it prints the currently processed line – in the first expression `{print}` was omitted as it is the default action. The output is saved in the file `out`, leave out `>out` to print to the terminal instead.

Source: [awk: print lines after match to end of file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/372105/246819)